# Meaning of $A^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Let $A$ be a matrix. I know that there is definition for $A^k$ power of $A$, and $e^A$ expontential of $A$.

Is there any meaning of $A^A$?

Comment: If you can compute the logarithm of $A$, then this could mean $e^{A\log A}$.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: In my head. I'm just curious.

Comment: Then what egreg suggests is the only possible definition I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes, I had the same idea, but I thought that somebody could say something more.

Comment: But sadly egreg's approach doesn't handle the situation, when $A$ is singular. I posted earlier an other question about this situations.

Comment: @user153012 Not just when $A$ is singular, there are many other instances, in $\mathbb R$, is which $\log (A)$ isn't defined. But so what? Many things aren't defined everywhere, not even the complex logarithm is defined at the origin.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence
"A matrix has a logarithm if and only if it is invertible. The logarithm is not unique, but if a matrix has no negative real eigenvalues, then it has a unique logarithm."

Comment: @user153012 I said in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok, you're right, but the link also answer this: "A real matrix has a real logarithm if and only if it is invertible and each Jordan block belonging to a negative eigenvalue occurs an even number of times."

Comment: There is the functional calculus where given any analytic function $g:\Omega \to \mathbb C$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$, you can define $g(A)$ for any matrix whose spectrum is contained in $\Omega$.  (It works for elements of general Banach algebras as well as matrices.)

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith can you say a numerical example for this approach?

Comment: @user153012 I didn't say how $g(A)$ was defined.  One place to read about it is Conway's book on Functional Analysis - I think - I know it is in one of his books.  It is done via contour integrals.